# UITextField in iOS7 simulator do not take any input from mac keyboard

Tags: uitextfield, ios7, xcode5

`UITextField` suddenly do not take any input from mac keyboard, However I am able to use the virtual keyboard coming up on `UIView` on iOS7.0 simulator.

Has any one resolved this issue before?

Comment: I recently switched to Xcode 5 and noticed that there is a setting that allows you to somehow customize how the OSx keyboard is mapped to the simulator keyboard.  Have not investigated the settings there, but there may be something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reset the `iOSSimulator`, its contents and settings and quit and relaunched the `iOS-simulator.` it worked.

This exactly happened when I updated the code from `SVN`.

I guess its always a good practice to clean the code, relaunch the simulator when ever updating the source code from SVN especially with `Xcode5`.

Answer (score 7):

In simulator menu:

Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

helped me with this problem

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a bug in the simulator.

Steps to reproduce (and fix)

1. Open simulator and for example Safari
2. Start typing along and it will work fine
3. Use CMD + LEFT or RIGHT arrow to rotate the device to landscape
4. Try typing using the mac keyboard and it will not work
5. Press and release the CMD key once and the keyboard is working again

I'll file a bug report with Apple now.

Comment: Thanks very much! Resetting the simulator a hundred times won't work, this is indeed the correct explanation. Thanks for sharing this information.

Answer (score 2):

Restart of simulator worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your programme unable to take input from mac keyboard then perform the following steps:

1. Open the simulator
2. Go to hardware option in Menu
3. Choose Keyboard> Connect Hardware Keyboard

**Shortcut**
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

[image]